# When to take maintenance exam for Salesforce Certified Administrator (SP17)

Tags: certification

I have passed Salesforce Certified Admin exam Spring17. DO I need to write the maintenance exam that is released for summer 17 to maintain my credentials?
I received an email from salesforce regarding this and looking at the schedule i am confused. The website says This exam is required if you earned the Salesforce Certified Administrator credential on or before July 13, 2017. When I login to webassessor, I can see the "Salesforce Certified Administrator - Summer '17 Release Exam" under the Certified Maintenance Exams and it says free to register.

Could any please clarify?

Many Thanks,
Sreehari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. you have to give maintainance exam for summer'17. Please refer to deadlines below.

[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answers your question.